# CSS3 support for IE7/8 using CSS3 PIE not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a web application that should be compatible with IE7, IE8 and IE9. Also i want to use `border-radius` and `box-shadow` attributes in CSS. I came across the [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/b) and i have added that into my project as below,

[image: PIE]

Then i created a `TextBox` and `Button` using `ASP.NET` and added the following styles in CSS file,

```
.textbox, .button
{
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(153, 0, 0);
    transition: 0.3s ease-in all;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 2px rgba(250, 250, 250, 2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 2px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 2px 1px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 30px;
    behavior: url(~/PIE/PIE.htc);
}
```

But the `border-radius` and `box-shadow` are not working in IE7 and IE8 even though i have used the CSS3 PIE plugin. They asked me to add the `position: relative;` and `z-index: 0;`, so i have added them. Also i have added the `behavior: url(/path/PIE/PIE.htc);` property but still this is not working. Am i doing something wrong here? I am using VS 2010 here.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've used PIE.htc, but if I remember correctly, there were a *lot* of missing things, or things that just didn't work as expected.  I don't have IE7 anymore or I'd help you figure it out... but in short, you just need to experiment until a certain hack works for you.  In the end, you might be better off with images.

Comment: @Brad yes i keep trying and making small changes to see if it works but im not sure what i am missing

Comment: I'd just go with images at this point then.  The other thing is that PIE.htc takes a ton of CPU, so if you use a lot of these, it will be very slow on any machines still running IE 7.

Comment: @Brad oh i see ok..But is there any other way apart from using image backgrounds? Like any other working plugin or JavaScript or JQuery code? or maybe possible to add within HTML itself?

Comment: PIE.htc is the best polyfill I know for IE 7.  Sorry, it's been so long, I don't remember a lot of the little tricks that IE 7 used to need.

Comment: @Brad I see ok thanks..In case you come across something or if you remember somethings please notify me